# How to add Image with a NSDictionary and send the List of Array to server using POST method in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, image-uploading

I'm working on a project where I need to add multiple `NSDictionary` object's into an `NSArray` and that `NSArray` need to be send to server using the POST request . For this I'm using `AFNetworking` framework . Well every thing worked fine till the time I came across a requirement of sending `Image's` with object in the array .
I tried sending the image data as `base64` string form , but the problem here is , when I tried sending the data this either take a lot of time and some time time's out and fails the connection . Well I tried with other way round of compressing the image and sending it but here the `UIImage` quality is affected . So can any one help me to do this in a right way.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSData *imagedata =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imgaddcontact.image);
    NSString *base64 = [imagedata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];      
  NSMutableDictionary *parameterdiction = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [parameterdiction setObject:base64 forKey:@"Photo"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"<URL>" parameters:parameterdiction constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
    {
        if(imagedata != nil)
        {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imagedata name:@"Photo" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input , here I have to send an array of object's. and not a single object , When I send a single object , it works perfectly , but when i try to send and array of object's including list of images , this gives me time out issue . I want to send all the NSDictionary object's with images in NSArray and send this array to the server .@purushothaman
Here the the above answer we can only send one object and not a list of object .. 
Thanks once again for your help , and can you please let me know how will it work for sending an NSArray of objets which includes images .

Comment: please did you get a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AFNetworking`. Drag and drop your library to your project and import `AFNetworking.h` in your class and then you can do something like below,

```
  // This request only depends on afnetworking
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:imageUploadUrl parameters:tempDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

 // retrieve image by any way in my case below in your case whatever
 UIImageView *tempImageView = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:imageViewBaseTag+i];
 UIImage *img = tempImageView.image; 
 NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);  //convert image to data to send

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:i] fileName:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];  // append image data to formdata to send server


} error:nil];



// This part is not depend on AFnetworking

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


    // handle your response here. you get respose in data parameter convert it in appropriate format like json or string and you can handle error also if occured

}]resume];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the input , here I have to send an array of object's. and not a single object of NSDictionary .

Comment: then you can pass that array of object instead of `tempDict` in `parameters`

Comment: NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5); 
is reducing the quality of the image . Can't we send the original  image .

Comment: If you want to sen multiple images also then you can take for loop inside block. don't mix both thing. Parameter is different thing and image is different thing

Comment: And i have post this code from my for loop so it is like so. you should manage according to your need

Comment: `[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:i]` this is simply returns image name string

Comment: and 
I guess there is a for loop for this line 
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:i] fileName:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];  // append image data to formdata to send server

Comment: Yes in my case i have written in for loop so it is like so. you can use as per your requirement.